# How old was Greedo when he was taken from Rodia?

Tags: star-wars, greedo

According to Canon, Greedo was born in 44 BBY. During his youth, he was taken from the swamp planet of Rodia and then he spent his early life in the desert planet of Tatooine in Mos Espa.

I've been looking for Greedo's early years in order to determine his age when he was taken from Rodia. There is a Canon event in Tatooine in 32 BBY where Greedo got into a fight with a nine-year-old Anakin Skywalker after accusing Anakin of cheating in the Boonta Eve Classic, prompting Qui-Gon Jinn to separate them. This supports the conclusion that Greedo was 12 years old when he fought Anakin.

There is another reference to Greedo's childhood. Tom and Martha Veitch's short story *"A Hunter's Fate: Greedo's Tale"* places a teenage Greedo in 4 BBY on Nar Shaddaa where his mother Neela tells him that he was two years old when they fled Rodia shortly after his father's death in 17 BBY, but this contradicts the Legend fact that Greedo was 27 (and not 2) years old at the time of his father's (Greedo the Elder, a famous bounty hunter).

I understand that there has been a lot of contadictions regarding the events of Greedo's childhood and early life either in Canon or Legends but I'm curious about how old Greedo was when he was taken from Rodia.

[image: Still image of Greedo on Tatooine in his youth from a deleted scene of The Phantom Menace]

Comment: Does “was hailed from” mean “was taken from” or “left”? I’ve not heard it used like that before.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I meant "taken from the place he originally lived/came from". Thanks.

Comment: @Bingo, your curiosity intrigues me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event you're referring to in Phantom Menace comes from [a deleted scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfUJwvzB6oQ), and hence is not canon, regardless of what Wookieepedia has to say on the subject.

Having gotten that out of the way, Pablo Hidalgo (in his [Essential Reader's Companion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Reader%27s_Companion)) had this to say on the subject of Greedo's early life;

> *THE STORY* [*Greedo's Tale*] *MAKES a number of assumptions regarding Greedo’s history that have since been disproven in the canon established by George Lucas. In the story, the Rodian is nineteen years old at the time of his death. A deleted scene from *Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace* (1999) shows Greedo as a child around the same age as Anakin Skywalker, and a denizen of Tatooine at the time, which would make him much older than nineteen at his death.*
>
> *The New Essential Guide to Characters (2002) attempted to preserve both stories by presenting the Episode I Greedo as “Greedo the Elder,” father to the younger Greedo depicted in “A Hunter’s Fate.” However, “Sphere of Influence,” a Season Three episode of Star Wars: The Clone Wars (2010), made this fix impossible, as **it is clear that Lucas intends Greedo to be an older, luckless hunter who has spent years on Tatooine trying to make a name for himself.***

So, the very short answer is that his history is inconsistent. He appears (in Legends) to have left Rodia *as a toddler* some time around 4BBY, but we really don't know. And to add to the confusion, Lucas certainly intended to have him on Tatooine around 32 BBY as a child roughly the same age as Anakin.

Comment: I think the intent of the pre-TCW Legends version is that he was a toddler in 17 BBY and was told about these events later in 4 BBY. Otherwise he'd be 6ish in A New Hope.

Answer (score 2):

### Canon: Between 0 and 12 years old

Greedo scuffling with Anakin as a kid is confirmed to be part of canon by the *Star Wars Character Encyclopedia*:

> GREEDO grew up on Tatooine and was known for his temper. He sometimes attempted to start fights with others, including Anakin Skywalker, who lived in Mos Espa.
>
> <sub>(Source: *Star Wars Character Encyclopedia, Updated and Expanded Edition*, page 124: Greedo)</sub>

The same source confirms that his homeworld was Rodia, though doesn't say when he left.